# How to get all children of a parent control in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin

I'm looking for an code example how to get all children of parent control in Xamarin.Forms.

Comment: use the `Children` property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can try to use the `Children` property of your control.

For example,there is a grid, we can access its `Children` like this:

```
        var children = grid.Children;

        foreach(View child in children){
            if (child is Entry) {
                string value = ((Entry)child).Text;

                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("one value is = " +  value);                
            }
        }
```